# What is the difference between these object initialisations?

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, copy-constructor

There are two type of object initialisation using copy constructor:

```
Class object2(val1, val2); // <--- (1)
```

Same can be done by copying the contents of another class:

```
Class object1(val1, val2);
Class object2 = object1;  // <--- (2)
```

**What is the difference between (1) and (2) ?** 
Are they explicit calls and implicit calls or does it have to do with operator overloading?

Comment: (1) is explicit construction, not copy construction.  (2) is copy assignment.  Copy construction would be `Class object2( object1 );`  If you don't overload the copy assignment operator, it will initialise the target object using the copy constructor.

Comment: 1 ==> class constructor ;  2 ==> copy constructor;

Comment: That mean that 2nd one copy constructor is being called. SO no overloading of = operator?

Comment: @paddy 2 will never result in a call to the copy assignment operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both constructs use constructors, but different constructors. First is a constructor taking two arguments, second is normally the copy constructor (can be defaulted). The explicit declarations should be like:

```
class Class {
    // constructor taking 2 args
    Class(int val1, const std::string& val2);
    // copy ctor
    Class(const Class& other);

    /* you could optionaly have a move ctor:
    Class(Class&& other); */
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

### 1. case 1

```
Class object2(val1, val2);
```

will call the constructor with two arguments

```
Class(type a, type b);
```

### 2. case 2

```
Class object2 = object1;
```

will call the copy constructor

```
Class(const Class&);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/IbjPT9)